# map function to values of dictionaries in list

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries and want to apply some function `f` to the same key of dictionaries. I can do it with for loop in multiple lines:

```
dicts = [d1, d2, d3]
for dict in dicts:
    dict['key'] = f(dict['key'])
```

So how can it be done in one line? 
Thanks

Comment: `for dict in (d1,d2,d3): dict['key'] = f(dict['key'])` No need to write `for` bodies on a new line :) That being said I don't see why writing *one liners* is a goal on its own. The idea of a one-liner is usually that it is an *elegant* way compared to others. But that is *not* always the case.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, but I expected something with list comprehentions or map functions =)

Comment: I apologise for this that is not the right comment in stack overflow but @Willem Van Onsem is awe-inspiring

Comment: Nope, this makes no sense!! The correct answer is you should not as you lose readability.

Comment: Could't you just change the function's parameter to be the whole dictionary and loop through the dictionary in the function instead?

Comment: @AnthonyPham no, it's a library function.

Comment: What is `'key'`? Updating a dictionary is not possible with a comprehension, creating a new dictionary is possible, so if you are iterating over all `'key'`s in a dictionary you could create a new list of dicts, e.g.: `[{key: f(d[key]) for key in d} for d in dicts]`. Note: don't use `dict` for a variable name it hides pythons builtin `dict` type.

Comment: you cannot directly change an existing object using comprehensions.  a comprehension returns a new object.  So you could theoretically create a set of comprehensions that returns a list of _new_ dictionaries whose contents are the same as the original dictionaries with the exception of the given key, but it would not affect the original list nor the original dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you with what you are looking for:

```
map(f, [dict[key] for dict in dicts if dict[key]])
```